# Using indirect to pull from multiple sheets for a Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a dynamic list of the sheets in a Google workbook. I am hoping to create a query that pulls from these different sheets - although I am often adding and deleting sheets.

Right now my query looks like, and it works great:

```
=query({'1.17 invoice'!A25:N;'1.31 invoice'!A25:N;'2.1 invoice'!A25:N;'invoice 2.1 (2)'!A25:N},"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col7, Col12, Col13 where Col1 <> ''",0)
```

I can create a cell A1 that has a value of: '1.17 invoice'!A25:N;'1.31 invoice'!A25:N;'2.1 invoice'!A25:N;'invoice 2.1 (2)'!A25:N

But right now I have to copy and paste the results of A1 into the query formula in order for it to update. When I try to create a formula like:

```
=query({indirect(A1)},"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col7, Col12, Col13 where Col1 <> ''",0)
```

I just get an error that 'the results of the indirect are not a valid cell range'. Is there any good way to automate getting the list of sheets into the query function?

Comment: Try this: `={'1.17 invoice'!A25:N;'1.31 invoice'!A25:N;'2.1 invoice'!A25:N;'invoice 2.1 (2)'!A25:N}`

Comment: Highly recommend that you read this answer by @Ruben (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88726/196152). It's the source for my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

The OP has tried to make the array range more flexible. Original formula:

```
=query({'1.17 invoice'!A25:N;
        '1.31 invoice'!A25:N;
         '2.1 invoice'!A25:N;
     'invoice 2.1 (2)'!A25:N},
 "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col7, Col12, Col13 where Col1 <> ''",0)
```

The OP entered the array range in cell A1, and modified the formula:

`A1 = '1.17 invoice'!A25:N;'1.31 invoice'!A25:N;'2.1 invoice'!A25:N;'invoice 2.1 (2)'!A25:N`

Modified formula:

```
=query({indirect(A1)},"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col7, Col12, Col13 where Col1 <> ''",0)
```

This doesn't work because `INDIRECT` returns a single array value, but A1 consists of several ranges. However, if each of the ranges is declared separately, the query will work.

---

**Layout:**

```
A1 = '1.17 invoice'!A25:N    
A2 = '1.31 invoice'!A25:N    
A3 = '2.1 invoice'!A25:N    
A4 = 'invoice 2.1 (2)'!A25:N
```

**Formula:**

```
=query({indirect(A1);
        Indirect(A2);
        indirect(A3);
        Indirect(A4)},
 "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col7, Col12, Col13 where Col1 <> ''",0)
```

Credit:
Ruben (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88726/196152)
Karl_S (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/104517/196152)